# How to configure ObjectFactory to call parameterized constructor structuremap

Tags: structuremap

**PLEASE: If my question isn't clear, please tell me and I'll try to rephrase it**

1. I need [Default Constructor] in LogOnModel, so it **can't** be removed.
2. LoadModel+ModelFactory and LogOnModel are physically in different files in different projects AND project2 has reference to project1 and NOT vice versa.

1 - Let say that
    **type=typeof(LogOnModel)**. When **ObjectFactory.GetInstance(t)** is called I want it to call the
    **parameterized** constructor of LogOnModel and pass it the @params

2 - If I'll add to the **parameterized** constructor of LogOnModel another parameter,for example

```
public LogOnModel(string param, IPageService pageService)
```

so ObjectFacytory should call this constructor without any problems

How to configure/initiate ObjectFactory, so this will work?

Thank you

**EDITED**

```
//Project1/file1.cs    
public void LoadModel(Type type, string param)  
{
     var factory = new ModelFactory();
     var model = factory.Get(type, **param**);
}
public class ModelFactory : IModelFactory
{
     public PageModel Get(Type t, **string param**)
     {            
         //NOW I NEED SOMEHOW TO PASS **param** TO EVERY INSTANCE THAT INHERITS FROM **PageModel**
         return ObjectFactory.GetInstance(t) as PageModel;
     }
}
//Project2/file2.cs
public class LogOnModel : PageModel
{        
     public LogOnModel()
     {
     }
     public LogOnModel(string param)
     {                        
     }              
}
public class Model2 : PageModel
{        
     public LogOnModel()
     {
     }
     public LogOnModel(string param)
     {                        
     }              
}
public class Model3 : PageModel
{        
     public LogOnModel()
     {
     }
     public LogOnModel(string param)
     {                        
     }              
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StructureMap will use the constructor with the most parameters by default, so that part is easy.  Then you just need to configure the value of param like so:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(i => {
    i.For<LogOnModel>().Use<LogOnModel>();
});
```

When you call the container, use the with method to pass in your parameter:

```
return ObjectFactory.With("param").EqualTo(param).GetInstance(t) as PageModel;
```

Comment: But the "param" is dynamic. LoadModel gets the "param" and I need to pass it to ModelFactory.Get, so when it will create Instance, it will pass pass "param" to the created Instance

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show your intended usage?  Your example does not show param being used anywhere...